# Is there a simpler syntax for using context variables within a consumer?

Tags: reactjs

```
<ThemeContext.Consumer>
  {({theme, toggleTheme}) => (
    <button
      onClick={toggleTheme}
      style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}>
      Toggle Theme
    </button>
  )}
</ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

I got the above code from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component).

Is there an alternative way of writing the second line? The curly brackets mixed with parentheses is kind of weird in my opinion, and I'd like to know if there's an alternative way of writing it.

Answer (score 4):

- **useContext**

You can use `useContext` hook, which lets you read the context and subscribe to its changes, and which is really convenient when you want to subscribe to the changes of multiple contexts:

```
function ThemeTogglerButton() {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext); 
  const { ... } = useContext(AnotherContext); 

  return (
    <button
      onClick={toggleTheme}
      style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}>
      Toggle Theme
    </button>
  );
}
```

[useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

- **HOC**

The second approach is to create an HOC, which lets you inject the context as props to your components:

**withTheme.jsx (HOC)** :

```
export const withTheme = Component => props => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {contextProps => <Component {...props} {...contextProps} />}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
);
```

**ThemeTogglerButton.jsx**:

```
import { withTheme } from "./withTheme"

const ThemeTogglerButton = ({ theme, toggleTheme }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={toggleTheme} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.background }}>
      Toggle Theme
    </button>
  );
}

export default withTheme(ThemeTogglerButton);
```

**App.jsx**:

```
import ThemeTogglerButton from "./ThemeTogglerButton";

const App = () => (
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={...}>
    <ThemeTogglerButton />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
)
```